# Adding entity mapping in code rather in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible to add mapping in code rather in hibernate.cfg.xml file??

I have one hibernate.cfg.xml file for several different servers and I would like to load the mapping dynamically and not from the cfg file.

Thank you!

Comment: For example:
If my hibernate.cfg.xml has this line:

<mapping class="com.test.User"/>

Then, I would like to remove it from cfg file and instantiate it using code. How to do that?? some code example would be appreciated.

Comment: Just have a look at the link I posted in my answer. The first examle answers exactly this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your entities using the JPA annotations. There are a lot of tutorials for this on the net, an example is [Hibernate Annotations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The answer that worked for me:

AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(hibernateCfgFileName);
config.addAnnotatedClass(Myclass.class);

Comment: Yes, the same information is available in the link shared by @BetaRide